# cannot load my default controller yii

Tags: php, yii

i have changed  my default controller to 'defaultController' => 'caem'. Evrythings working fine in localhot. But when i upload all my works into remote server, it couldn't load my default controller but loaded siteController. How can fix it to load my default controller

Answer (score 1):

my  'defaultController' was 'caem' so my controller name should be CaemController with the first later capitalized. But in my case it was caemController, that why it doesn'T work. windows is not rigid in case sensitive but unix is. SO should pay more attention on case sensitive